# jQuery or onClick Div Fade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this is in the wrong section..

Could someone possibly point me towards a script or a tutorial on this:

when I click on something, say for instance an "x", I'll click it, then it fades away on click.

If you understand what I mean, could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: google for some jquery tutorials.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Yes, there is a LOT of reference material out there. This is a place for asking questions when you're stuck, but in general, it's a good idea to come here after doing some basic research, first.

Comment: you should ask a question after google search and try out some coding first

Comment: hahaha, alright. My fault guys!

Comment: u need to explain more clearly width the code.or explain where ur struck.search google 1st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/

There is small tutorials for different UI elements with good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Please familiarize yourself with Google.

Then familiarize yourself with http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works

Try out some code on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I did, but everything I was typing, wasn't making sense. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

[refer](http://jsfiddle.net/8bCAg/)

```
$('someclass/id').click(function() {
$('someclass/id').fadeOut();
});
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453710/fadeout-div-after-onclick-event-problem)

```
$('a').toggle(
function() { $('#us').fadeIn(); },
function() { $('#us').fadeOut(); }
);
```

[.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

show( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Its easy you could have googled that.

```
jQuery('#divId').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).hide('slow'); //this will give a little animated effect.
 // or
  jQUery(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: try to google the same thing,Or you can find many such things on SO as well.You can post in here in case you face a problem which you are unable to sort out yourself.Asking basic questions will earn you a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This describes how to fade in and fade out an element on click

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#elemntID").click(function() { 
    $("#ID_of_element_need_to_fade_in").fadeIn("slow");
  });

  $("#elemntID").click(function() { 
    $("#ID_of_element_need_to_fade_out").fadeOut("slow"); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#id').click(function() {
$('#id').fadeIn();
$('#id').fadeOut(); 

});
[link][1]
<script>
$("button:first").click(function() {
$("p:first").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
$("button:last").click(function () {
$("p:last").fadeToggle("fast", function () {
 $("#log").append("<div>finished</div>");
});
});
</script>
```